# C# Telegram.Bot (Bot.SendPhotoAsync). Как отправлять картинки без сжатия?

Tags: c#, telegram

При отправке через Bot.SendPhotoAsync картинка теряет в качестве, решил использовать Bot.SendDocumentAsync но файл отправляеться без расширения, c названием document. Скриншот https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MLIg.jpg

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-SendPhotoAsync

```
            case "/screenshot":
                await Bot.SendChatActionAsync(message.Chat.Id, ChatAction.UploadDocument);

                Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty));
                using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
                {
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                    {
                        g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
                    }
                    bitmap.Save("C:/Windows/Temp/screen.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
                const string screen = @"C:/Windows/Temp/screen.jpg";
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(screen, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                {
                    await Bot.SendPhotoAsync(
                        chatId: message.Chat.Id,
                        photo: new InputOnlineFile(fileStream),
                        caption: "Screenshot !"
                    );
                }
                break;
```

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=SendDocumentAsync

```
            case "/screenshot":
                await Bot.SendChatActionAsync(message.Chat.Id, ChatAction.UploadDocument);

                Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty));
                using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
                {
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                    {
                        g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
                    }
                    bitmap.Save("C:/Windows/Temp/screen.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
                const string screen = @"C:/Windows/Temp/screen.jpg";
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(screen, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                {
                    await Bot.SendDocumentAsync(
                        chatId: message.Chat.Id,
                        document: new InputOnlineFile(fileStream),
                        caption: "Screenshot!"
                    );
                }
                break;
```

Answer (score 1):

После конвертирования потока в `InputOnlineFile` нужно этой переменной в поле `FileName` присвоить имя с раширением (например: text.txt)

---

Я могу ошибаться, но понимаю это так. У нас есть поток данных, который мы упаковываем в одно из полей составной переменной. Чтобы эта переменная стала чем то определенным, а не потоком, мы даем ей имя, ну и расширения там же вписывается. Вы ведь можете поменять расширение файла при изменении имени, если у Вас видны они в проводнике.